# SQLCipher in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, sqlcipher

SQLite is available for WinRT. Is it possible to use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) with SQLite in WinRT  applications? If not is there any other way to encrypt data in SQLite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general our goal is to have SQLCipher work on the widest possible range of platforms, so we are definitely interested in supporting it. However, SQLite only recently added upstream support for WinRT in 3.7.13, and we haven't had sufficient time to investigate what is involved with getting SQLCipher working there yet. 
Please keep an eye out for future updates, or if you or your company has a funded commercial requirement for this sooner, reach out to us at support@zetetic.net.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. I'm looking forward to WinRT SQLCipher update.

Answer (score 1):

It was released on windows phone 8 and windows RT platforms recently (though only like Commercial Edition, link below).

[sqlcipher-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-runtim](http://sqlcipher.net/blog/2014/1/13/introducing-sqlcipher-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-runtim.html)